# Getting Infinispan lock holder thread

Tags: hibernate, locking, infinispan

We have clustered server application with a quite old Hibernate and Infinispan dependencies:

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-infinispan:4.3.8.Final
org.infinispan:infinispan-embedded:7.2.3.Final
```

Unfortunately we got the following exception on client request threads:

```
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 180 seconds for key <myKey> and requestor GlobalTransaction:<cluster-main1-60783>:4480123069:local. Lock is held by GlobalTransaction:<cluster-main1-60783>:4479604524:local, while request came from local
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl.lock(LockManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl.acquireLock(LockManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockKeyAndCheckOwnership(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:183)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.lockAndRegisterBackupLock(AbstractTxLockingInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor.acquireAllLocks(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:253)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.OptimisticLockingInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.NotificationInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(NotificationInterceptor.java:36)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptorAndVerifyTransaction(TxInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor.visitPrepareCommand(TxInterceptor.java:125)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPrepareCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleAll(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor.handleDefault(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.infinispan.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitPrepareCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.commands.tx.PrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(PrepareCommand.java:123)
    at org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain.invoke(InterceptorChain.java:336)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.prepare(TransactionCoordinator.java:121)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.prepare(TransactionCoordinator.java:104)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.synchronization.SynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationAdapter.java:44)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.fireBeforeCompletionEvent(BitronixTransaction.java:543)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.commit(BitronixTransaction.java:241)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.commit(BitronixTransactionManager.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransaction.doCommit(JtaTransaction.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180)
    ...
```

Is there any way to figure out which thread is holding the acquired lock?

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to Dan's answer we have used something similar to the code below to figure out what is the key in the exception message and which cache should we look for:

```
import org.infinispan.Cache;
import org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl;
import org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManager;
import org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManager;
 
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
 
EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = ...
 
setAccessibility(true);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
Set cacheNames = new TreeSet(cacheManager.getCacheNames());
for (String cacheName: cacheNames) {
    boolean createIfAbsent = false;
    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName, createIfAbsent);
    if (cache instanceof CacheImpl) {
        CacheImpl cacheImpl = (CacheImpl) cache;
        LockManager lockManager = cacheImpl.getLockManager();
        if (lockManager.getNumberOfLocksHeld() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        result.append("cache: ").append(cacheName).append("\n");
        result.append(" held: ").append(lockManager.getNumberOfLocksHeld()).append("\n");
        result.append(" available: ").append(lockManager.getNumberOfLocksAvailable()).append("\n");
        result.append(" concurrency level: ").append(lockManager.getConcurrencyLevel()).append("\n");
        result.append(" lock container: ").append(lockManager.lockContainer.getClass()).append("\n");
        result.append(" ").append(lockManager.printLockInfo());
        result.append("\n\n");
    } else {
        result.append("cache: ").append(cacheName).append("\n");
        result.append(" unknown cache type (template?): ").append(cache).append("\n");
        result.append("\n\n");
    }
}
 
return result.toString();
```

Comment: Good idea, I didn't consider that you could modify the application code. You don't have to cast to `CacheImpl` though, you can use `cache.getAdvancedCache().getLockManager()` instead, which will also work in newer versions on Infinispan.

Answer (score 1):

Infinispan locks are supposed to work when the initiator of the transaction is a remote node, or when the application suspends the transaction and resumes it on another thread, so locks are associated with transactions, not with threads.

As such, the only way to find which thread started the transaction that holds a particular key is to enable trace logging ahead of time on e.g. `org.infinispan.util.concurrent.locks.LockManagerImpl`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've also added our debug code too.